# webkit transition syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-transitions

I'm looking for the webkitTransition object reference here

```
 function spawnAnimation(what){
    //sets the moving element
    var moveingEl = document.getElementById(what);
    //gives temp transition property
    moveingEl.style.WebkitTransition = "left 2s";
   // moveingEl.style.webkitTransition = "top 500ms";

   var cLeft = moveingEl.style.left
   var cleft = Number(cLeft.slice(0, -2));

    var cTop = moveingEl.style.top
   var cTop = Number(cTop.slice(0, -2));

   moveingEl.style.left = cLeft+200 + "px";

}
```

This does not work.I would like to give the element a transition property, then make it move to the right. When this code is called it just immediately moves to the right with no animation. bummer :(. I don't want to predefine it in CSS, I would like to dynamically add it and then remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [style.setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) to modify any property using its CSS name as string, including `-moz-*` and `-webkit-*` properties.

```js
const style =  document.getElementById('my-div').style
const prop = (k, v) => style.setProperty(k, v)

function bounce() {
  prop("-webkit-transition", "top .5s ease-in");
  prop("top", "50px");
  setTimeout(() => {
    prop("-webkit-transition", "top .75s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000)");
    prop("top", "0px");
  }, .5 * 1000)
}

prop("-webkit-transition", "top .5s ease-in");
setInterval(bounce, (.75 + .5) * 1000);
```

```css
#my-div {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: That wasn't me man. Don't assume it was voted down by me just because of that comment. I appreciate your help and voted up to counter that negative, and to show my appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

Allow 1ms for the rendered to get the thread back.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myElement.style.height = '200px'; /* or whatever css changes you want to do */
}, 1);​
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when trying to animate a transform with a transition. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a reliable solution. You should use `window.requestAnimationFrame` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`element.style.webkitTransition = "set your transition up here"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

                var x = 100;
                var y = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                x += 1;
                y += 1;
                var element = document.getElementById('cube');
                element.style.webkitTransform = "translateZ(-100px) rotateY("+x+"deg) rotateX("+y+"deg)"; //for safari and chrome
                element.style.MozTransform = "translateZ(-100px) rotateY("+x+"deg) rotateX("+y+"deg)"; //for firefox
            },50);
            //for other browsers use:   "msTransform",    "OTransform",    "transform"

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a workaround, but can you use jQuery?

```
$(moveingEl).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(200px)');
```