# How do I get this transition to work in webkit?

Tags: javascript, webkit, css-transitions

I've have had success when using style sheets, but doing it in JavaScript isn't working for me. I need to do this programatically. Hopefully you will have realised that I'm trying to make the div 'grow'.

```
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.style.height = '0px';
myElement.style.padding = '0px';
myElement.style.webkitTransition = '2s'; /* problem with this line ? */
myElement.style.height = '200px';
```

Comment: You created an element, but didn't add it to the DOM

Comment: you mean like this... layout.messageBox.insertBefore( alert, layout.messageBox.firstChild );

Comment: possible duplicate of [webkit transition syntax in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411305/webkit-transition-syntax-in-javascript)

Comment: @AlvinWong is that all that you think is wrong?

Comment: @Bergi unfortuantely the other question doesn't offer a solution.

Comment: shadowing alert, not adding it in the dom, wrong syntax for the transition and not forcing reflow are the issues from the top of my head

Comment: @tomwrong: the solution there [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/7b4VZ/48/)

Comment: @Esailija okay thanks, I've changed the variable name. Now according to  Bergi and his down syndrome child example, *.style.setProperty() is the way forward which I have tried without success. So, what do you mean by forcing reflow?

Comment: @tomwrong setting a timer to change the height implicitly does it already. If you want it to animate right as you insert it, you need to force reflow (by writing `alert.offsetWidth;` for example) and then change the property you want to animate. It's not pretty but it's much prettier than a 1 ms timer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for you input. It all makes sense now. Points all round!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with css3, but according to [what I've tried](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9VE/4/) this work:

```
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.style.height = '0px';
myElement.style.padding = '0px';
myElement.style.height = '0';
myElement.style.webkitTransition = '2s';
// Append the element to DOM
document.getElementById("a").appendChild(myElement);
// Alter the height after forcing a reflow
myElement.offsetWidth=myElement.offsetWidth;
myElement.style.height = '200px';​
/*// Alter the height later
setTimeout(function() {
    myElement.style.height = '200px';
}, 1);​*/
```

Thanks to Esailija, you need to force a reflow, as stated in [this answer of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278213/1386111). Accessing properties such as `offsetWidth` will force a reflow, so that's a better way than a timer.

Comment: BINGO. Nice one. so the timeout allows the renderer some 'breathing' time. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's to do with giving the thread up to the renderer first. The timeout obviously sets an even which won't fire until the renderer catches up

Comment: ahh okay. 'reflow', good word to know. Slowing getting this web browser thang.

Comment: personally I prefer the timeout but i THINK it does the same thing. It does make me ever so curious as to exactly WHY the myElement.offsetWidth=myElement.offsetWidth works.